# require_once(dirname(__FILE__)): Failed to open stream

Tags: php, file

There may be a super easy fix to this that I am completely missing. I've looked around Stack Overflow and other answers say that what I am doing now should work.

I am trying to require a `config.php` so I can get the credentials to a database. I am requiring it via `require_once (dirname(__FILE__) . "/../../config.php");` The file that I am referencing the method from (config.php) is located at `/internal/CloudShop/login` config.php is located at `/internal/config.php` But, when I load the page, I get this error

```
Warning: require_once(C:\xampp\htdocs\CloudShop\internal\CloudShop/../../config.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\CloudShop\internal\CloudShop\login.php on line 48

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\htdocs\CloudShop\internal\CloudShop/../../config.php' (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\CloudShop\internal\CloudShop\login.php on line 48
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Looking for the file in the wrong place?

Comment: you are searching on dir to far ithink, lose /.. one time

Comment: A guess:  Don't use forward slashes on Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script where you execute `require_once(...)` is in `/internal/CloudShop`. You are looking for a file that is in `/internal`. Therefore you need to go only 1 directory above in the hierarchy, not two.

```
require_once (dirname(__FILE__) . "/../config.php");
```

will do the trick.

Comment: I read it as, it's coming from inside the directory `login`, not a script named `login.php`

Comment: Bleh... I scrolled far enough to see `\CloudShop\internal\CloudShop` but not the rest of it  =P